# What is the meaning of the FORCE keyword in a CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

What does the keyword FORCE mean in this statement:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE object_name FORCE IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

Comment: I don't understand why there are 4 close votes for _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic"_  ? Where the OP is asking for some off-site resources ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I think people were using it as "RTFM". But you're right. I wasn't the right reason to close this question.

Comment: It *is* in the docs... but they're pretty terse. Having a decent explanation here is useful IMHO

Answer (score 10):

It means forcing (re)creation of the type, even if it has other type dependencies. For instance, if you have these types:

```
type O_Object is (
  Prop1 INT,
  Prop2 INT
);
type T_ObjectTable is table of O_Object;
```

If you would like to modify O_Object, you will get an error, because T_ObjectTable depends on it. Using FORCE, you can recreate the object (though T_ObjectTable will need recompiling afterwards).

This won't work though if there are table dependencies (*actual* tables, not table-of-object *types*). In that case, the create statement will fail with or without FORCE.

[It's in the docs too](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/create_type.htm) :)